# Vuetify - Add Tooltip to Button that is triggering a datepicker

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to add a v-tooltip to the v-btn I'm using to trigger the datepicker for a my charting application. Here is code that is working, before attempting to integrate the tooltip.

```
    <v-menu ref="menu" v-model="menu"
      :close-on-content-click="true"
      :return-value.sync="date"
      transition="scale-transition"
      offset-y
      min-width="290px"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn v-on="on"
          :style="{left: '50%', transform:'translateX(-50%)'}"
          light
          icon
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker 
        v-model="date" 
        no-title 
        scrollable
        >
      </v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
```

With the above, I click the button, I get the datepicker, all is good.  I have tried a bunch of different ways to add a v-tooltip, e.g. wrapping the whole block, wrapping just the template and wrapping just the button.  Wherever I place the tooltip code, it breaks the whole setup in that either the button doesn't show or the click on it isn't processed.

Buttons being ideal for tooltips, to reveal their functionality without having to click to find out, this seems like a reasonable thing to do.  It is easy to use v-btn to trigger lists, but I find very few examples of people using buttons to display datepickers, even though lots of people are asking questions online about it.  I'm hoping there is a technique for tooltips that can be used with a variety of pickers actuated from .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it for you, try now:

#### Demo: https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/vYNdJwO?editors=1010

```html
<v-menu
  ref="menu" 
  v-model="menu"
  :close-on-content-click="false"
  transition="scale-transition"
  offset-y
  min-width="290px"
>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu }">
    <v-tooltip bottom>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on: tooltip }">
        <v-btn 
          v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...menu }"
          :style="{left: '50%', transform:'translateX(-50%)'}"
          light
          icon
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>Tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>
  <v-date-picker 
    v-model="date" 
    no-title 
    scrollable
    >
  </v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: Wow Alex, that was quick!  Studying what you did there by adding an additional template to wrap the v-tooltip, targeting events to specific refs...  there is some wisdom there that I need to try and understand better.  THANKS for providing an on-ramp to getting  better acquainted with this activator stuff.  It seems to work differently depending on which components you're using.

Comment: @SARogersz glad I could help. Nested slots can be difficult to understand. When you are attaching 2 components to the same activator like this, you have to use spread syntax `{ ...tooltip, ...menu }` to merge both objects into 1. If you're not familiar with spread syntax, you can read about it [here](https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/how-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-javascript-b9e4a8b06fab) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Hey Alex, I hope you can help with taking this one more step - to actually update the date.  From the codepen I was unable to produce an update from the datepicker, and this is part of the syndrome I was observing with my own experiments before I posted this.  Is there also some magic there?  I feel like I'm following the pattern and keeping it simple... all I did was add {{ date }} to show the value and operating the datepicker doesn't change it.  I verified that if I initialize date to a string it shows right away.

Comment: @SARogersz I updated the answer and the codepen. It didn't work because initially you set the property `:close-on-content-click="true"` which was closing the menu before the date was picked, and also I removed the property `:return-value.sync="date"`. Now it works as intended

Comment: Extremely helpful Alex.  I'm new to asking questions on Stackexchange, so I don't know how best to mark this answer as the one, but I feel this answer does the job!

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, but unfortunately I get a syntax error on ```...tooltip```, ie, the spread operator. I have a relatively new vue-cli project, created April 2020. From some googling, it looks like this might be related to Babel, and the need for a plugin, but nothing i've tried so far seems to work.

Comment: Note that I was using this within a vue component, and that's where the spread operator wasn't working (see prev comment). Turns out in JS code, the spread operator works fine. So to solve it, I changed ```{ ...tooltip, ...menu }``` to ```spreadArgs( tooltip, menu )``` where ```spreadArgs``` is just a method in the component.

Comment: @Jack thanks for sharing your solution. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you in the `<template>` since `v-on` should be able to run any JS code. Try to add the following code somewhere in your template: `<div v-text="{...{a: '1'}, ...{b: '2'}}"></div>` if you see a single joined object rendered on your page, it means you probably made a typo in your `v-on` (previous comment). I usually get that `Babel needs additional loaders` error when I make a typo in my code.

Comment: @AlexHoffman Yeah that works fine, and the bottom line, is that it works in v-on as well. The issue is that the project is configured with eslint, and eslint generates 2 errors: ```'v-on' directives require that attribute value or verb modifiers```, and ```Parsing error: Line 1: unexpected token``` pointing to the spread operator. I don't even know what the 1st complaint is about. But the page works fine, I just assumed because of the errors that it didn't. In any event, I like a clean lint, so I'm leaving my solution in place.